# YouTube API - Search for video in specific channel

Tags: javascript, search, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube API on javascript in order to get all videos from a specific channel:

```
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?",{
    part : 'contentDetails',
    id : '..............',
    key: "..........................."},
    function(data) {
            ............................................
});
```

How can I search in that specific channel for videos by using a keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
function searchVideo(input) {
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", 
        {
            q: input,
            part : 'snippet',
            channelId : '...........',
            key: "........."
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                ....................
            });
        }
    );
}
```

There is one problem though. The results are wrong all the time. What could be the case here?

Comment: Could you define 'wrong' ? My guess, what is the value of 'input' ?

Comment: I mean inaccurate. Completely inaccurate. For example i type 'boat' and I get 5 results and only one of them contains the word 'boat'. Plus I have to add here that the video titles main language is greek

Comment: Well the endpoint is used by a gajillion people, so I would double check your parameters. Echo the finished url to the screen and copy it here for us to look at.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: here it is: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?&q='boat'&part=snippet&maxResults=10&regionCode=GR&type=video&channelId=UCyZYQ2xLqZctoxrLCdIuheQ&key=...

Comment: So I compared the results from that URL to the results at YouTube and they are virtually the same. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyZYQ2xLqZctoxrLCdIuheQ/search?query=boat

Comment: huh, you're right, nothing changes. I suppose this is a Youtube issue and I can't change anything. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Use the YouTube [search:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint instead.

It takes both a `channelID` and a `q` parameter for searches.

Comment: Could I use this using Jquery get?